# Collabnet subversion server reaching CPU 100% because of httpd.exe process

Tags: windows, apache, svn, collabnet

I have Collabnet subversion edge installed on my windows server 2008 R2 standard (x64 bit)). I am using only Collabnet subversion with apache configured manually configured by me.

svn version is 1.8.13 and apache version is 2.4.12.

Authentication: using AD
CPU:4
RAM:16 GB

Problem statement: server is going down again and again because it is reaching CPU 100%. When i checked which process is causing this issue, i can see that it is httpd.exe consuming all cpu when i just kill it cpu will come down to zero.

So far i am not successful in identifying what is the exact root cause for this, however in the error log i found one line which says `[mpm_winnt:error] [pid 3448:tid 3040] AH00326: Server ran out of threads to server requests. Consider raising the ThreadsPerChild setting`. After going through apache documentation i came to know that we have a mpm (multi process module) module to handle the number of threads per child, so did the below change in my httpd.conf:

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
  ThreadsPerChild 200
 MaxConnectionPerChild 10000
</IfModule>
```

And also did one more change after going through some web links which says LDAP caching also cause CPU reaching 100% hence, i made caching zero using the below line

```
LDAPSharedCacheSize 0.
```

After the above two changes my server was running fine for one month.
Looks like it has a side effect. I got the complaint from my user that: every day first fetch to the repository is taking time. then i removed `LDAPSharedCacheSize 0` from my httpd.conf But, vary next day CPU again reached 100%.

Can anybody help me if my configuration is wrong or i need to modify the configuration in my httpd.conf?

Comment: You may want to try [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/). It works out of the box and you don't need to configure apache manually.